# How do you turn off Virtualization Technology (VT-x) on an Intel Core 2 Duo E6600?

Tags: virtualization, vt-x

I'm trying to turn off Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) on my Intel Core 2 Duo E6600, and I've got an Asus P5N32-E SLI LGA 775 nForce 680i motherboard.

I looked through all the bios settings and couldn't find anything do do with virtualization or VT-x.

I need to turn virtualization off so I can boot Mac OS X in VMware.

Comment: You should edit out the last line for legal reasons.

Comment: Depending on where he is it's not necessarily illegal.

Comment: Depending on where he is in NY? He is also on someones website and it doesn't look good.  If I was in Timbuktu and asked how I could rip DVDs and download video cam rips it still wouldn't be kosher.

Comment: If there are problems with this question, flag it and explain to the moderator. If you need feedback, go post on http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Neil, manual says it's in the BIOS under `Extreme Tweaker -> Virtualization Technology` http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5N32-E%20SLI/e2929_P5N32-E_SLI.pdf, so you must have missed it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple can't mandate by law that someone must follow their arbitrary rules in their software license. Running an operating system on "unapproved hardware" can hardly be illegal. The VM being the hardware.

Comment: Apart from saying that I agree with Neil, I'd like to add that Apple do approve of running Mac OS X Server in a VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have overlooked, it is in the **Extreme Tweaker** menu under **Overclocking** section.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable it from BIOS. Press f2 on boot to see the bios settings. Now goto Security > VT Technology (Enable/Disable)

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

VT/NX dosen't need to be disabled for OS X to work in VMware in my experience. It might be method dependant - i'm using a boot132 cd

Comment: I couldn't boot OS X before I disabled VT-x, but now I can with VT-x off. Before I could only restore from a snapshot.